Boot drops to shell and requires manual lvm vgchange -ay
Seems to be a similar issue to boot hangs and needs manual 'lvm vgchange -ay' but this is for a Ubuntu 24.04 installation (and none of the other suggestions seem to be fixing it)
This is a Dell Poweredge T30 server using Intel's Software RAID controller to create a 4-disk RAID 5 split into two partitions on each disk; one for the boot partition and one for the root partition.  Initially it had Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it, but it's been upgraded over the years and today it went from 22.04 to 24.04.
After rebooting it'll hang, with a few 'device md126 is still in use' messages; I have no idea if these are normal or not because typically this part of the boot flies past fast enough that on a working config I can't actually read any of this.  However, md126 is the RAID that contains my root volume group.  This volume group is not activated automatically on the new kernel, and drops me to a shell saying that vg_root-Root can't be found.
However, a quick lvm pvscan is quick to find it and lvm vgchange -ay successfully activates it and I can exit the shell and boot normally.  As this is meant to be a headless server though this is mildly annoying.
I've tried adding a udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules with the line:
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add|change", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}="raid", RUN+="watershed sh -c '/sbin/lvm vgscan; /sbin/lvm vgchange -a y'"
As well as adding /sbin/lvm vgchange -ay to /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block/lvm2 and /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block/lvm2.
However these all lead to the same outcome.
I had also updated the volume group metadata since that was out of date (using vgck --updatemetadata vg_root) since grub was complaining about that when I ran update-grub but this didn't have any impact.  I've also played around with changing /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to have both most modules and only dependencies, but neither seems to offer any changes.
Booting from kernel 5.15 - the latest from 22.04 - boots successfully.
(Suggested in boot hangs and needs manual 'lvm vgchange -ay')
So far I'm at a bit of a loss here.  None of the old suggestions seem to work and I'd really rather not nuke and reinstall the system, as although I have backups I really just don't want the downtime restoring them since they're not on the fastest storage.

So it seems that it was possibly some weirdness in the kernel (since the old kernel worked but the new one didn't).  I wound up just upgrading to 24.10 (and the 6.11 kernel) which did the trick.
In retrospect I probably could have used mainline to install a newer kernel without getting off of the LTS (so that I wouldn't have to upgrade every few months for the next couple of years) but I didn't think of that until after the upgrade had completed.
However, a newer kernel does seem to be the solution for this.  The one shipped with 24.04 seems to have some issues with that system.
